# SQL IN working but NOT IN does not work

Tags: sql, null, exists, sql-in

I have this query that will return correctly the values that are part of the `IN` clause, but when I change it to `NOT IN`, it does not return anything.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
select distinct 
    CAST( w.work_area AS CHAR(4) ) || s.code_id as WATT 
from 
    sys_code s, 
    work_area_master w 
where 
    s.code_type = '590' 
    and (
        CAST( w.work_area AS CHAR(4)) || s.code_id
    )  
    in (
        select substr(misc_flags, 1,6) 
        from sys_code where code_type = 'STA'
    );
```

Comment: Hint: NULLs will make `IN` behave differently from what you expect.

Comment: Either `NULL`s are messing with your results, or every row is in that select

Comment: The `FROM sys_code s, work_area_master w` looks uncorrelated. Mybe you want to JOIN them on some common keyfield?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One could include a coalesce function like this:

```
select distinct CAST( w.work_area AS CHAR(4) ) || s.code_id as WATT
from sys_code s, work_area_master w
where s.code_type = '590' 
and (CAST( w.work_area AS CHAR(4)) || s.code_id) in (
select substr(coalesce(misc_flags,"    "), 1,6)
from sys_code
where code_type = 'STA'
);
```

Comment: Do not encourage the use of a SQL antipattern of implicit joins. In this case it appears he has a cross  join which may or may not be what he wants and the next person to maintain this won't know if it was a bug or intentional. This is especially dangerous if a later change adds and addtional code_type.

Comment: I agree with you HLGEM. However, some crossjoins can be fully implemented if this is the deliberate intention of the programmer. That's why I firmly believe one of the best practices is to comment on code, rather than letting someone else understand what was the author's intent on creating such a code.

Comment: If you use explict joins you can only have a cross join if you write one. That is one of the reasons why the implict join is an extremely poor idea if you intend one as your intentinos are not clear. Even if you comment, comments are so often out of date that many devs won't realize it was still pertinent. If you use code, the intention is always clear.

Comment: Brilliant HLGEM! Thanks for pointing that. I'll look forward on my own code to avoid such a trap.

Answer (score 1):

The Exclusion Principle (ie, that A or ~A is a tautology) does NOT apply whenever A may be NULL. When nullable fields exist, three valued loigc applies and the Exclusion Principle must be modified to ( A or ~A or A is NULL).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST( w.work_area AS CHAR(4) ) || s.code_id AS what 
FROM sys_code s
JOIN work_area_master w ON 1=1 
WHERE s.code_type = '590' 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sys_code xx
    WHERE xx.code_type = 'STA'
    AND substr(xx.misc_flags, 1,6) = CAST( w.work_area AS CHAR(4)) || s.code_id
    );
```

Footnote: I deliberately used the `JOIN ... ON 1=1` syntax to draw attention to the fact that the original query did not even have a join condition (except for the one in the *correlated* IN subquery)

Comment: If you mean to have a cross join, write one using the the CROSS JOIN syntax. Don't join on 1=1

Comment: Why? This one stands out more (I still don't know if it is the OP's intention to do a carhesian product, except for the subquery)

Comment: `EXISTS` >> `IN`. And I took the liberty to make it a proper `CROSS JOIN` - I hope that's ok with you.

Comment: I Hate the syntactic sugar. for me `1=1` reads easyer than all the fuzz words.

Comment: Sorry to have interfered then, roll back the change if you disagree. I do think it's better to user proper `CROSS JOIN`, though.

Comment: Becasue 1=1 is meaningless and will confuse later developers. CROSS JOIN is clear.

Comment: So I did. I think I can afford a personal style. Besides, it is an entirely different issue. No, 1=1 is NOT meaningless. It draws the attention, more than a buzzy keyword. There are already too many keywords in SQL.

Comment: Well, I disagree, but it's a valid POV. +1 on the solution with `EXISTS`.

Comment: The construct `IN ( *correlated* subquery)` is even worse, IMHO. It is valid syntax, but sloppy semantics.

Answer (score 0):

The check whether the combination of `sys_code` and `work_area_master` is valid can actually *be* the `JOIN` condition.

Also using `EXISTS` instead of `IN` to avoid problems with `NULL` like [@wilplasser already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15394439/939860):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CAST( w.work_area AS CHAR(4) ) || s.code_id AS what 
FROM   sys_code s
JOIN   work_area_master w ON EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM   sys_code x
          WHERE  x.code_type = 'STA'
          AND    substr(x.misc_flags, 1,6)
                 = CAST(w.work_area AS CHAR(4)) || s.code_id
          )
WHERE  s.code_type = '590' ;
```

For a detailed explanation of the problem with `NOT IN` and `NULL`, refer to this [closely related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17407/why-does-not-in-with-a-set-containing-null-always-return-false-null).